# Where in the C++11 standard is std::fmodf stated?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std, fmodf

According to the [cppref page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod), std::fmodf was added to cmath in C++11. How is this possible though, because wouldn't this mean that cmath would break compatability with math.h previous to C++11? I'm unable to find any references that say std::fmodf was added in C++11 and was wondering where this is stated.

Thank you

Comment: Why would it break compatibility?

Comment: Adding doesn't break compatibility.  Removing an interface would.

Comment: @interjay hmm, I think you're right. However I can't find any references to std::fmodf in the C++11 standard? Did C++11 add support for C99 functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where in the C++11 standard is std::fmodf stated?

It wasn't mentioned directly (although it probably should have been mentioned either in the list of functions, or explicitly omitted). The change that causes `std::fmodf` to exist  is here (quote from draft N3337):

> The following referenced documents are indispensable for the application of this document. For dated references, only the edition cited applies. For undated references, the latest edition of the referenced document (including any amendments) applies.
>
> - ...
> - ISO/IEC 9899:**1999**, Programming languages — C
> - ...

Through the following rule:

> [c.math]
>
> The contents of these headers are the same as the Standard C library headers <math.h> and <stdlib.h> respectively, with the following changes: ...

C99 added fmodf. It was inherited to C++ when C++11 started referring to the standard library of C99 instead of C89.

Note, the "following changes" do not list omission of `fmodf`.

---

> Why isn't fmodf listed in the list of  functions (26.8/3 and 26.8/9)? It was added to the list in the C++17 standard.

This appears to have been an editorial mistake. It seems to have been fixed in C++17 by [P0175](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0175r1.html) which proposes:

> In this editorial paper we propose to add to the working draft the complete synopses of the C library headers that are included in C++ by reference to the C standard (see Table 15). These synopses will replace the various tables captioned “Header  synopsis”.

---

Sidenote: `std::fmodf` is fairly useless in C++, since you can simply use `std::fmod` instead, and that has been around since C++98.

Comment: Why isn't `fmodf` listed in the list of `<cmath>` functions (26.8/3 and 26.8/9)? It was added to the list in the C++17 standard.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I was thinking of this after seeing that C99 added fmodf and such.